# PHP: Form prevent multiple tabs.

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm currently using javascript to prevent link to be opened on multiple browser tabs every time user click on it. Let say my link destination is google, it will create a new tab if not exist but refresh if same destination exist. And it works good so far.

Here is the code.

Link

```
<div id="container">
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(test){
        if (test.target.tagName === "A")
            window.open(test.target.href, test.target.href);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

My question is, How can I use same JavaScript on my form with similar effect? I mean if user submit my form. It will create a new tab when submitted if it not exist. But resubmit on same tab if the tab is exist. I tried to change JavaScript but can't make it work as normal link.

Here is my form

```
<form name='form1'  action='/newform.php' method='post' target='_blank'>
<input type='hidden' name='test' value=''>
<input type='image' src='../data/images/myimages.gif' width='100px' height='30px' alt=''>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't, not like that. Difference is that in first you are using `window.open` and in the other you are using `target = _blank`. In the second you do not have the control of the tab.

Comment: I don't get it sir. Because I also use target = _blank on my link. Can't figure it out why my form keep creating new tabs with same url when submitted instead of 1. Unlike my link that only create 1 tab.

Comment: Your target=_blank on your link has no effect, because you are using window.open in your javascript and opening the window like that. If you remove the target=_blank from your link, it will also work, because it is not the link opening the tab, it is the script.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. But is there any way to make my form work same way as link? I think Javascript need to adjust so my form can work same way. I tried to modify javascript but still can't make it work. My form keep create new tabs when submitted instead of re-post on same tab :(

Comment: Have a look at example I just wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function formSubmit() {
        window.open("about:blank","newWindow");
    }
</script>
<form name='form1'  action='/newform.php' method='post' onSubmit='formSubmit()' target='newWindow'>
  <input type='hidden' name='test' value=''>
  <input type='image' src='../data/images/myimages.gif' width='100px' height='30px' alt=''>
</form>
```

Basically, this will open new window when the form is submitted for the first time, and every other time form will submit to the already open window.

Keep in mind that `window.open` can be blocked by popup blockers and often is.

Comment: Sorry for late reply sir. I just test it. And your code do exactly as I look for. Same way as my link did. I got 2 newbie questions. 1) Can "newWindow" at [window.open("about:blank","newWindow"] rename into other? 2) As you mentioned above, window.open can be blocked by popup blockers, is it still work same as target=_blank or different method?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a session variable?
Also use ID's for javascript.

```
<?php 
  //Check if session has not been started.
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
  {
    session_start();
  }


//If it has not been set, set no default.
if (!ISSET($_SESSION['hasSubmit'])
{
    $_SESSION['hasSubmit'] = "no";
}

if ($_SESSION['hasSubmit'] == "no")
{
   //Execute code for no
  echo "
  <form name='form1'  id='firstSubmit' action='/newform.php' method='post' target='_blank'>
  <input type='hidden' name='test' value=''>
  <input type='image' src='../data/images/myimages.gif' width='100px' height='30px' alt=''>
  </form>";
}
else if($_SESSION['hasSubmit'] == "yes")
{
   //Execute code for yes
   //Edit your form properties here to your likes.
  echo "
  <form name='form1'  action='#' method='post' target='_newblank'>
  <input type='hidden' name='test' value=''>
  <input type='image' src='../data/images/myimages.gif' width='100px' height='30px' alt=''>
  </form>";
}
?>
```

in newform.php set:

```
$_SESSION['hasSubmit'] = 'yes'
```

now the javascript:

```
$('firstSubmit').click(function(){
location.reload;
});
```

this should do the trick

Comment: Will it create more tabs with that? Assume I have tab 1 with form.php and submit it will create tab 2 with newform.php. What if I back to tab 1 and resubmit, will it create tab 3 with newform.php?

Comment: To resolve this problem, create a onclick handler in javascript, executing a location.reload(); I will edit my answer to your question.